# How to go back to Previous Activity when Back button is pressed?

Tags: android, back-button

I am developing Android application. When I press the back button, 
it says the application is stopped.

Below is my code:

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                switch(position){

                case 1 : Intent intent = new Intent(Product.this, Desktop.class);

                         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                         startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                         break;
                case 2 : Intent intent1 = new Intent(Product.this, Notebook.class);
                         intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                         startActivityForResult(intent1, 2);

                         break;

               default : break;

                }
            }   
        });



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.desktop);


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, comps));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                   getApplicationContext(),
                   ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                   .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

What should I add so that it will go to the previous activity?

Comment: nothing. that works out of the box. you just need to read what SINGLE_TOP does.

Comment: I am not getting How to use that in my application?

Comment: You don't write to anywhere Android itself kills your activity when you press BACK button. Just resolve your other issues. Just Remove `intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` from Intent and **override** `onActivityResult()` in your Current Activity.

Comment: @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    
    finish();
    return false;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   
  }

Comment: @Patil Please see my answer it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code snippet instead of your code, may be it will solve your problem.

```
case 1 : Intent intent = new Intent(Product.this, Desktop.class);
         startActivity(intent);

         break;

case 2 : Intent intent1 = new Intent(Product.this, Notebook.class);
         startActivity(intent1);

         break;
```